# Dual Bootable OS in single Flash drive?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I want to use Ubuntu as well as Windows using 1 flash drive. (32GB)
Is it possible?

I mean it should show both Ubuntu as well as Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but....

**Issue #1:**

While it is possible to have more than one partition on a usb flash drive, many tools will fail when attempting to format it. I would suggest using Gparted under an Ubuntu livecd to get around that, as it sometimes works.

**Issue #2:**

Unless your flash drive has amazing write/read speeds it's going to be unberrably slow at running Windows (unless you're running Windows To Go, or WindowsPE). Trust me; I used to have Windows 7 installed on an sd memory card and the only way to make it semi usable was to create a massive page file on a faster storage device. Ubuntu isn't going to run great either, but it's not as bad.

**Issue #3:**

Most editions of Windows don't allow installation on usb devices because then people could run a single copy of Windows on multiple computers and Microsoft would lose money. Such editions of Windows are designed to interrupt the usb input at boot making it impossible to boot Windows from them unless it's been modified not to do so. If you want to install & be able to run Windows from a usb stick you will need to use either Windows To Go which is only for Windows 8 Enterprise, Windows Embedded, Windows PE (which is a miminal environment that due to minimal .netframework support can't run much software-wise), or figure out how to modify Windows to allow both installation, and running from a usb device. I did see a guide doing this on XP once, but that was years ago; I've no idea if it actually worked.

**Issue #4:**

Given you're trying to fit 2 operating systems into 32GB of space you will need to keep in mind what programs you intend to install on them, because you may not have enough room. Windows Embedded is a space saver if you leave out SxS. Additionally both operating systems have space requirements that they will refuse to install below (even if they would actually fit).

**Notes:**

You will run into multiple issues if you plan on using these usb installations on other computers because they are configured for your computer's hardware. Windows will also be activated to a given computer so attempting to run it on others will require constant re-activation which could get your license key blacklisted.